# How to set a page's flag in kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, flags

Assume I want to set a page dirty in kernel, can I just emulate it like this:

```
#define PG_dirty 4
struct page page1;
page1.flags |= (1 << PG_dirty);
```

Then this page is marked dirty?
I see there is a macro in `<mm.h>`

```
#define SetPageDirty(page)      set_bit(PG_dirty, &(page)->flags)
```

It seems that `set_bit` does a lot more things.

Comment: `set_bit` sets given bit *atomically*, that is concurrent processes cannot see flags in intermediate state. E.g., [set_bit implementation on x86](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/boot/bitops.h#L38) uses `btsl`  asm instruction. BTW, if you found `SetPageDirty` macro, no needs to reinvent its implementation - just use the macro.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to fake this in the user space, that's why I can not use `SetPageDirty`. By the way, I know the reason for using the bitwise OR in the expression (set some bit in the flags to be 1, right?). But I don't understand why it does bit shifts first `1 << PG_dirty`.

Comment: `1 << PG_dirty` gives value, where only bit numbered `PG_dirty` (counted from 0) is set, other bits are cleared.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks buddy. Got it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm sorry to bother you, but what if I want to clear the dirt mark of this page and remain other bits unchanged? Is `page1.flags &= ~(1 << PG_dirty);` correct?

Comment: Almost. Correct expression for clear bit: `flags &= ~(1UL << PG_dirty)`. The thing is that you need operator `~` being applied to value as long as `flags` variable(`unsigned long`). Otherwise, you wouldn't set high bits.